# How doi I compose subscriptions with RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

Is this a good way to compose different subscriptions/streams?

I'm creating 2 programs (terminal streams) that start each other up and run until the clean up function that is returned is called.

```
const program = () => {
  let activeSubscription;

  const program1 = () => fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(take(10)).subscribe(
    console.log,
    console.error,
    () => { activeSubscription = program2() }
  )

  const program2 = () => fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(take(10)).subscribe(
    console.log,
    console.error,
    () => { activeSubscription = program1()
  )

  // Return clean up function
  return () => activeSubscription && activeSubscription.unsubscribe()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to avoid dealing with multiple subscriptions and combine observables in a single stream:

```js
concat(
    fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(take(10), tap(() => console.log('move'))),
    fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(take(10), tap(() => console.log('click')))
).pipe(repeat()).subscribe();
```

This way you don't have to subscribe right away and your `program` can return observable to be piped/subscribed later somewhere else. It gives more flexibility.

Comment: That's what I was looking for! I'm building quite a complex application though but I'm trying to use operators like these to make it behave like a state machine.

Answer (score 1):

In the Angular world we have used the standard of using a takeUntil on each subscription with a finalise subject. That way in your clean up function you emit down a single subject and all other subscriptions are cleaned up.

```
const program = () => {
  let finalise = new Subject();

  const program1 = () => fromEvent(document, 'mousemove').pipe(take(10), takeUntil(finalise)).subscribe(
    console.log,
    console.error
  )

  const program2 = () => fromEvent(document, 'click').pipe(take(10), takeUntil(finalise)).subscribe(
    console.log,
    console.error
  )

  // Return clean up function
  return () => {
    finalise.next();
    finalise.complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice clean solution. I'd still be starting up the previous program in the subscription's `complete` callback though. When _program1_ is done, _program2_ starts, and vice versa.